# $det(I+A(\epsilon))$ where $A$ is an infinite matrix and not trace class!

Tags: matrices, determinant, infinite-matrices

Assume that $A$ is an infinite matrix and it's a function of the parameter $\epsilon$. I would like to find $\epsilon$ so that the $det(I+A(\epsilon))=0$.

I know if $A$ was a trace class I could use the Fredholm identity, i.e. 
\begin{equation}
det(I+A)=\prod_{n\geq 1} (1+\lambda_{n})
\end{equation}

where $\lambda_{n}$'s are eigenvalues of $A$.

In my case however, $A$ is not a trace class but it is symmetric and I know it's eigenvalues $\lambda_{n}(\epsilon)$. I was wondering if there is an identity similar to this that I can use. Also, how good of an approximation this would be if I truncate the product for a large $n$?

Comment: what is your definition for determinant for an infinite matrix ?

Comment: Note that $\prod(1 + \lambda_n)$ converges iff $\sum \lambda_n$ converges.